# FFmpeg for iOS5

Tags: ios, ios5, ffmpeg

Has anyone been able to compile ffmpeg libraries using the iOS5 sdk?  I have found scripts that use the 4.3 sdk but nothing for iOS5.  I would assume that libraries built with the old sdk and armv7 will still be compatible for iOS 5.

Here is the command I am trying to use:

```
./configure \ --cc=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc \ --as='gas-preprocessor.pl /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc' \ --sysroot=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk \ --extra-ldflags=-L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib/system \ --target-os=darwin \ --arch=arm \ --cpu=cortex-a8 \ --extra-cflags='-arch armv7' \ --extra-ldflags='-arch armv7' \ --prefix=compiled/armv7 \ --enable-pic \ --enable-cross-compile \ --disable-armv5te \ --disable-ffmpeg \ --disable-ffplay \ --disable-ffserver \ --disable-ffprobe \ --disable-doc
```

I have also tried using a script like this one:

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f

if (! -d armv7) mkdir armv7
if (! -d lib) mkdir lib

rm armv7/*.a

make clean

./configure --disable-doc --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --enable-cross-compile --arch=arm --target-os=darwin --cc=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc --as='gas-preprocessor/gas-preprocessor.pl /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc' --sysroot=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk --cpu=cortex-a8 --extra-cflags='-arch armv7' --extra-ldflags='-arch armv7' --enable-pic

make

mv libavcodec/libavcodec.a armv7/
mv libavdevice/libavdevice.a armv7/
mv libavformat/libavformat.a armv7/
mv libavutil/libavutil.a armv7/
mv libswscale/libswscale.a armv7/

rm lib/*.a

cp armv7/*.a lib/
```

I have also tried to switch to the gcc-4.2 as well as the llvm-gcc-4.2.  However I get an "Unknown option" error shown below in the comments.

Any info will be great and thanks.

Comment: It should compile absolutely fine AFAIK. Are you seeing any specific errors when compiling using the iOS 5 toolchain?

Comment: Unknown option "--cc=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc".  The gcc compiler looks like it is in there.  Any suggestions?

Comment: That's right, you'll need to use `llvm-gcc` or `clang` rather than `gcc`. Do you understand how to do that or are you trying to use a script or something similar to compile it?

Comment: I have tried using scripts and just running the command from terminal

Comment: What script exactly? I can try fixing it for you - I've been compiling ffmpeg for ios for a while so should be able to sort it out!

Comment: I put the script in the question above

Comment: try changing gcc to llvm-gcc for option -CC. Also you could try llvm-gcc-4.2

Comment: See this answer for link talking about legal issues WRT including ffmpeg in an iOS app: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832754/trying-to-compile-the-ffmpeg-libraries-for-iphoneos-platform-with-armv6-and-arv7/17202184#17202184

Answer (score 17):

***UPDATED:*** Completely changed the answer to use the script that I use.

You will also need to download `gas-preprocessor.pl` from `https://github.com/yuvi/gas-preprocessor`, put it in your path and make it executable.

Then create a script (say `make_for_iphone.sh`) and put this in it:

```
export PLATFORM="iPhoneOS"
export MIN_VERSION="4.0"
export MAX_VERSION="5.0"
export DEVROOT=/Developer/Platforms/${PLATFORM}.platform/Developer
export SDKROOT=$DEVROOT/SDKs/${PLATFORM}${MAX_VERSION}.sdk
export CC=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/llvm-gcc
export LD=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/ld
export CPP=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/cpp
export CXX=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/llvm-g++
export AR=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/ar
export LIBTOOL=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/libtool
export NM=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/nm
export CXXCPP=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/cpp
export RANLIB=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/ranlib

COMMONFLAGS="-pipe -gdwarf-2 -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot ${SDKROOT} -marm -fPIC"
export LDFLAGS="${COMMONFLAGS} -fPIC"
export CFLAGS="${COMMONFLAGS} -fvisibility=hidden"
export CXXFLAGS="${COMMONFLAGS} -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden"

FFMPEG_LIBS="libavcodec libavdevice libavformat libavutil libswscale"

echo "Building armv6..."

make clean
./configure \
    --cpu=arm1176jzf-s \
    --extra-cflags='-arch armv6 -miphoneos-version-min=${MIN_VERSION} -mthumb' \
    --extra-ldflags='-arch armv6 -miphoneos-version-min=${MIN_VERSION}' \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --arch=arm \
    --target-os=darwin \
    --cc=${CC} \
    --sysroot=${SDKROOT} \
    --prefix=installed \
    --disable-network \
    --disable-decoders \
    --disable-muxers \
    --disable-demuxers \
    --disable-devices \
    --disable-parsers \
    --disable-encoders \
    --disable-protocols \
    --disable-filters \
    --disable-bsfs \
    --enable-decoder=h264 \
    --enable-decoder=svq3 \
    --enable-gpl \
    --enable-pic \
    --disable-doc
perl -pi -e 's/HAVE_INLINE_ASM 1/HAVE_INLINE_ASM 0/' config.h
make -j3

mkdir -p build.armv6
for i in ${FFMPEG_LIBS}; do cp ./$i/$i.a ./build.armv6/; done

echo "Building armv7..."

make clean
./configure \
    --cpu=cortex-a8 \
    --extra-cflags='-arch armv7 -miphoneos-version-min=${MIN_VERSION} -mthumb' \
    --extra-ldflags='-arch armv7 -miphoneos-version-min=${MIN_VERSION}' \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --arch=arm \
    --target-os=darwin \
    --cc=${CC} \
    --sysroot=${SDKROOT} \
    --prefix=installed \
    --disable-network \
    --disable-decoders \
    --disable-muxers \
    --disable-demuxers \
    --disable-devices \
    --disable-parsers \
    --disable-encoders \
    --disable-protocols \
    --disable-filters \
    --disable-bsfs \
    --enable-decoder=h264 \
    --enable-decoder=svq3 \
    --enable-gpl \
    --enable-pic \
    --disable-doc
perl -pi -e 's/HAVE_INLINE_ASM 1/HAVE_INLINE_ASM 0/' config.h
make -j3

mkdir -p build.armv7
for i in ${FFMPEG_LIBS}; do cp ./$i/$i.a ./build.armv7/; done

mkdir -p build.universal
for i in ${FFMPEG_LIBS}; do lipo -create ./build.armv7/$i.a ./build.armv6/$i.a -output ./build.universal/$i.a; done

for i in ${FFMPEG_LIBS}; do cp ./build.universal/$i.a ./$i/$i.a; done

make install
```

This compiles both armv6 and armv7 versions and puts them into a fat library using `lipo`. It installs to a folder underneath where you run the script from called `installed`.

Note that at the moment I've had to turn off inline assembly using a `perl` inline replace to change `HAVE_INLINE_ASM` from `1` to `0`. This is because of this problem with `gas-preprocessor.pl` - https://github.com/yuvi/gas-preprocessor/issues/16.

Also note that this has turned off all encoders, decoders, muxers, demuxers, etc except for the H264 decoder. Just change the configure lines to compile what you want for your use case.

Please remember also that this has enabled GPL code - so you should be aware about what that means for iPhone apps. If you're not aware then you should do some reading about that.

Comment: error:Unknown option "--cc=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc".

Comment: When I run the script I get: make: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop.
./configure: Command not found.
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Comment: Matt, I've compiled ffmpeg using your script and it works great. However, when dragging the .a files into Xcode and compiling I'm getting 'Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: "_avcodec_init", referenced from:....' Any thoughts ?

Comment: Sounds like it's not got the armv7 part. Any errors when you compile?

Comment: don't you need the file protocol enabled?

Answer (score 3):

Here is my working Configure for cross-compiling `FFmpeg` on iOS 6 the arch is `ARMv7`

**NOTE: You must have to have [gas-preprocessor.pl](https://github.com/yuvi/gas-preprocessor) inside `/usr/local/bin/` please do not continue until you have [gas-preprocessor.pl](https://github.com/yuvi/gas-preprocessor) on your bin directory**

- Download FFmpeg 1.0 "Angel" from [here](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html)
- Unzip it and place it somewhere i.e. your `Desktop` folder
- Open terminal and browse to `unzipped FFmpeg folder`
- Copy and paste the following command, (**be patient will take a while**)

> ./configure --disable-doc --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --enable-cross-compile --arch=arm --target-os=darwin --cc=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc --as='gas-preprocessor/gas-preprocessor.pl /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc' --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk --cpu=cortex-a8 --extra-cflags='-arch armv7' --extra-ldflags='-arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk' --enable-pic --enable-decoder=rawvideo --disable-asm

- Now type the following command on terminal `make` (**wait a little more**)
- Once it has finished now type on terminal `sudo make install` (**wait again**)
- Go to `/usr/local/lib` to find your freshly baked `armv7` libs
- Enjoy!

Alex

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. I only had to install pkg-config before running ./configure.

Answer (score 1):

I've created an "ffmpeg4ios" project at https://github.com/ciphor/ffmpeg4ios, which is successfully compiled on iOS 5.0.
You can check it.