# Compress video like iOS's camera roll

Tags: ios, video, compression

**Background:**

I am recording a video and then uploading it.

**Problem:**

I compressed the video using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5853354/1276636) (medium quality) but it doesn't:

- keep the original dimensions of the video
- have as good a compression ratio as camera roll's.

I need similar compression (size and dimensions) like camera roll.
If it's not possible, do we have a workaround, say, automatically select the file from the iOS video picker (for upload)?

Comment: FFMPEG can help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323672/ffmpeg-for-ios5

Answer (score 0):

You can use AVAssetWriter and set custom compression settings.  You can even compress the video while you're recording so you don't have to re-process the video before upload.  Search around, there's tons of examples.