# Compile FFMpeg for Xcode 5 without GCC?

Tags: ios, xcode, gcc, ffmpeg, clang

I'm trying to compile FFMpeg to add to my iOS app project in Xcode5, however since GCC is no longer included the ./configure script included with FFMpeg doesn't work. Unix/Linux is NOT my strong suit so I'm pretty much at a loss as to what to do next. I know I can install GCC manually, but if FFMpeg is compiled with GCC and the rest of my project is compiled with LLVC/Clang/whatever won't it cause problems. I did manage to install FFmpeg with Brew but I'm not sure what that even accomplished since it wasn't done using options flags like below:

`./configure --prefix=armv7 --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --enable-avresample --enable-cross-compile --sysroot="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk" --target-os=darwin --cc="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc" --extra-cflags="-arch armv7 -mfpu=neon -miphoneos-version-min=6.1" --extra-ldflags="-arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=6.1" --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a9 --enable-pic`

None of the scripts/fixes I've tried work, even if they're advertised as working in IOS7/Xcode 5, because they all use GCC. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try compiling it with clang

```
--cc="/usr/bin/clang"
```

`llvm-gcc` is another option.

Have you seen suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19092796/build-ffmpeg-with-xcode-5) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323672/ffmpeg-for-ios5)?

Comment: I am unable to compile it for i386 though. At the end ofconfig.log file I'm getting: `Unable to identify target architecture at /usr/bin/gas-preprocessor.pl line 82.
GNU assembler not found, install gas-preprocessor.` I definitely have gas-preprocessor in /usr/bin. Also when I was doing 'make' on the arm7 builds, I got a lot of this. `warning: value size does not match register size specified by the constraint and modifier [-Wasm-operand-widths]` Is this anything to be concerned about?